# Am new in android development how to fix this?

Tags: android

actually i started android development 2-3 days ago i don't know how to fix this???

here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.himanshu.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void myFunc(View view){

    Log.i("new", "new");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TEst", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

when i try to run this app on emulator this didn't work and i also my button ID is myFunc
here is LogCat

> 07-24 16:24:03.722 3416-3416/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>    07-24 16:24:03.723 3416-3416/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86 07-24 16:24:03.780 3416-3416/com.example.himanshu.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.himanshu.myapplication-1/lib/x86
>                                                                                     [ 07-24 16:24:03.791  1505: 1530 D/         ]
>                                                                                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x91016200, tid 1530 07-24 16:24:03.803 3416-3416/com.example.himanshu.myapplication I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.example.himanshu.myapplication, real application class is null. 07-24 16:24:04.093 3416-3416/com.example.himanshu.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.himanshu.myapplication-1/lib/x86 07-24 16:24:04.190 3416-3416/com.example.himanshu.myapplication W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable 07-24 16:24:04.325 3416-3416/com.example.himanshu.myapplication W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed
>   [ 07-24 16:24:04.325  3416: 3416 D/         ]
>   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xab0add80, tid 3416
>   [ 07-24 16:24:04.372  3416: 3438 D/         ]
>                                                                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9f60f280, tid 3438 07-24 16:24:04.388 3416-3438/com.example.himanshu.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4 07-24 16:24:04.388 3416-3438/com.example.himanshu.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1 07-24 16:24:04.390 3416-3438/com.example.himanshu.myapplication W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without... 07-24 16:24:04.390 3416-3438/com.example.himanshu.myapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0 07-24 16:25:11.717 3416-3437/com.example.himanshu.myapplication W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.example.himanshu.myapplication/lib

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.himanshu.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard- 
      rules.pro'
    }
}
  }

  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 }
```

Comment: Is `myFunc()` being called anywhere in your code?  If _not_, then I see no reason why your first activity should not at least startup.  Another option here would be to add a breakpoint on the `super.onCreate` line, and then step through to see what is happening.

Comment: post your activity_main.xml code

Comment: the method is not called anywhere

Comment: try testing your app in real devise. or emulator with api 5.0 or above, i am sure you won't get this error

Comment: tried this also but not working

Comment: can you post your gradle file?

Comment: here is activity_main.xml https://ghostbin.com/paste/6pfgd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the xml that you posted:(https://ghostbin.com/paste/6pfgd)

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/myFunc"
.../>
```

you access you button in the activity using the following code:

```
Button myButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myFunc);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myFunc();
        }
    });
}

public void myFunc() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, "TEst", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

there is another way to use the method `myfunc` without the need to reference the button, you should change your layout to:

```
<Button
    android:onClick="myFunc"
.../>
```

then you leave the method myFunc as it is:

```
public void myFunc(View view){
   Log.i("new", "new");
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TEst", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and it's working fine on Ubuntu 16.04 LTE. API level is 25 and Android version is 7.1.1
here is the xml code for the button

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/myFunc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="myFunc"

    />
```

and the function you defined in your MainActivity is

```
 public    void myFunc(View view){
    Log.i("new", "new");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "TEst", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

here is the onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: when i tried your xml code it's working but when i tried mine it did't work why??

Comment: @AnuChaudhary i think the problem is in his xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
        public void myFunc(View view) {

            Log.i("new", "new");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity1.this, "TEst", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }}



    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity1">


    <Button android:id="@+id/myFunc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:onClick="myFunc"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Anything different?

Comment: your answer is just assumption. and its completely wrong. you see  myFunc(View view) is OnClickListener which is called through xml. so this mathod will called only if specific view will be clicked. please real full question before answering.

Comment: Himanshu himself said that its not being called anywhere and of course, you are also assuming that its been assigned to a view.

Comment: Could you pls share your xml also? and pls explain " i also my button ID is myFunc here is LogCat"

Comment: dear, fun(View view) means its called from xml. and as per his saying that method is not getting called anywhere, how can it be cause the problem if it not getting called. your whole answer is based on that method is called or not.

Comment: and i mean to say that my button ID is myFunc and also am putting my logs in question

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh God i found solution 
here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.himanshu.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:id="@+id/myFunc"
    android:onClick="myFunc" />
```

here in my xml code i forgot to add myFunc in onClick attribute but when i added it works...

And also sorry for this noobish question am new in android development.. thanx for everyone